# stream to byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, stream, byte

I'm creating a program in native C++ (no clr). I'm using a toolkit which converts data and normally writes it to a file or stdout.
The issue is that I want to write it to an array and I don't know the size which will be sent.
The toolkit requires a paramter "FILE *" and cannot be modified.

Basically working code:

```
FILE * ofile = fopen("yourfile.dat", "wb");
toolkit::function(ofile);
fclose(ofile);
```

to std out the first line would be

```
FILE * ofile = stdout;
```

What I want now, is that I have can perform the function end in the end have a pointer to an array op byte (e.g. char *) and the size of it.
I've been looking around an can find the sollution.
First writing to a file is not an option.

Comment: This question is completely unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want a FILE* object that will store all bytes that were written to it in a memory buffer, right?

`fmemopen` does exactly this job, but is POSIX.1-2008 and according to its manpage not widely available.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look further into it.